# Please help me identify this connector type

Tags: connector, identification

Can anyone help me identify this connector types? I have tried finding this connector online and the closest one seems to be tamiya connector. But the ones I found being sold online has different locking mechanism.

[image]
[image]

This is the female counter parts:

[image]

It's used for a washing machine coin sensor.

Comment: Sharing the dimensions and contact pitch would be helpful for quicker identification.

Comment: What is the connector used for, what does it connect and where? Context might be useful to know if this is a hobby servo connector or RC battery connector.

Comment: It's used for a washing machine coin sensor. I will upload the photo of the female counter parts. I'm not with the machine right now, so I will update the dimensions later on.

Comment: Instead of guessing at a replacement, why not buy BOTH male & female inline pieces - Then you'll "know" you got it right.   Would take trivially longer to replace both of them.      Note the crimping bit can be tricky if you don't have the right tool, but you can buy these with the wire already attached so it's a just a splicing job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that sure looks like molex mini-fit JR

https://www.digikey.co.nz/product-detail/en/molex/0015311032/WM2586-ND/2405493
https://www.digikey.co.nz/product-detail/en/molex/1726460313/WM20748-ND/5116928

contact pins and crimp tool sold separately.